# Adding CSS in both custom theme and admin theme

Tags: theming, commerce, ubercart

How to modify some css to a `tapir_table` display being used in both places:
in my custom theme and administration theme

Specifically, i would like to make the qty and sku columns displayed on both ***my_website.local/user/1/orders/2*** and ***my_website.local/admin/store/orders/2*** align to the left, instead of center (the way ubercart's *uc_order.css* has it).

In my custom theme, it was as easy as modifying the *style.css* file and adding this css:

```
.order-pane-table td.qty, .order-pane-table td.sku {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

but i was wondering if there is a way to do the same for the administration display without modifying the admin theme or create a sub-theme of that admin theme.

Comment: Create a small custom module, define a library and add it on hook_page_attachments or hook_preprocess_HOOK.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for docs which already exist on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module).